# vimeo embedded video covering full visible height and screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, iframe, vimeo

I have a embedded vimeo video but the issue is that it's not covering the entire width of  the visible screen.  It covers the height.
I have set width and height to 100vw and 100vh respectively.[image: here is the screen shot of the issue I'm facing]

The code is as follows

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" >


<section id="videoplayersection">


<div id="videoplayer">

<!--
<img alt="" src="../images/b1.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="randomimg">

<h1 id="wedname">A weds B</h1> -->
<div id="playerholder" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/287060201" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<!-- <p>
  <a href="https://vimeo.com/287060201">Dolomites - a timelapse adventure</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/casperrolsted">Casper Rolsted</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.
</p> -->
</div>

<div id="story"class="container">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="story-content ">
<p>
Taj and Atisha, two people from two different countries and two different cultures. Taj, West Indian and Atisha, a Sri Lankan, both brought up in England. They connected with each other through common friends at that time and found themselves to be extremely one with each other. Atisha loves her&nbsp; prosecco, and Taj loves barbecues.&nbsp; Their friends are their family, they do nothing without them. And so, they decided to have a small little destination wedding here in Goa with just their closest of the closest friends and their parents at the beautiful Stone Water Eco Resort.


</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- <div class="wthree_title_agile">
 <p id="heartunderline"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div> -->


 

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="../js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

here is the css part

```css
.story-content {
    position: relative;
    /* padding:0px 220px; */
}

.story-content p {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 8%;
    padding-right: 8%;
}

#story {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#videodiv {
    position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .story-content p {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .story-content p {
        padding-left: 8%;
        padding-right: 8%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .story-content p {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .story-content p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    .story-content p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 400px) {
    .story-content p {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    iframe {
        /* display: block; */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /* object-fit: cover; */
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    #playerholder {
        /* position: absolute; */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    iframe {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
    #playerholder {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    iframe {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the width of iframe to 100%; if I do so nothing changes.
If I change height of iframe to 100% and width 100vh/100%; it increases its height and does not fit the visible screen.

Comment: Not covering the entire width of what, exactly?

Comment: width of the visible screen

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to suggest a solution here. With the code provided I do not see the same issue you describe in my browser. The display itself, the aspect ratio of it, and so forth could be playing a role.

Comment: could you suggest what extra information should be added?

Comment: If you can post the full source code of a page that reproduces the problem, or a link to a public page that shows the problem, that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, more details on the actual environment where you are seeing the issue. Browser, display, OS, etc.

Comment: It is always resize in a aspect ratio. You can't stretch in both direction like image.

Comment: @barbecue  I have posted the complete code. I am using google chrome as my browser

Comment: @AmbujKhanna so this will be the max width for a laptop screen/desktop screen  right?

Comment: @AmeyBhivshet Yes. it will take 1 side max value only.

Comment: @AmbujKhanna thanks for clearing my doubt would have wasted a lot of time trying to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance you may want to try changing **object-fit: contain** to object-fit: fill, or even removing it. object-fit controls how an object is scaled to fit a container, and it sounds like your issue is with scaling, so try experimenting with those values. If you can edit your original question to include more details about the environment and the exact effect you're seeing that would be helpful.

Comment: Tried both no change.
I'll edit the question and paste the complete html file as well as the css file